# Doctrine: Persisting certain entities leads to no change in db

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a fixture class that extends Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture and I am reading in a bunch of csv tables where the data is hard coded.

It worked all well and I introduced more and more entity classes (User, Location, etc) until one of the files (Topic.csv) where `persist($entity)` suddenly had no effect.
Loading the fixture leaves the table "topics" still completely empty. No error message, nothing shows up in the logs.

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
        
        // Here some magic happens that converts each line into an associative array 
        // e.g. [['id' => 1, 'Name' => 'Bob', 'Age' => 21, ...], ['id' => 2, ...]]
        
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $create_method = 'create' . $shortClassName;   // e.g. createUser
            $entity = $this->$create_method($row);
            $this->om->persist($entity);

            // This part below is to ignore @ORM\GeneratedValue and use the given id values
            // instead
            // $this->om has the class Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager
            
            $metadata = $this->om->getClassMetaData(get_class($entity));  
            $metadata->setIdGeneratorType(\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::GENERATOR_TYPE_NONE);
        }
        $this->om->flush();
}
```

Using my debugger I can see that the entities are created and look good and are handed to the object manager, but after the persistance action I can't find any of them in the UnitOfWork or any trace of the persistance at all. As if the Topic-entities were silently discarded.

*Does anyone have any idea of how I could continue debugging? Where should I put breakpoints to see why these entities never end up in my database?*

I am running Symfony 5.1 and my doctrine/persistance is currently at 1.3.7.

Comment: You should [batch flush](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/batch-processing.html#bulk-inserts) entities. e.g., if there is 1000 rows in a file, flushed once which mush be avoided at all costs.

Comment: Can you add your model class to your question? (User)

Comment: Are you using transactions?

Comment: sounds like Topic is different from other entities, maybe you should append one working and one non-working entity (class def that is!) to your question ?

Comment: @S.LT: While trying to put together a minimal example (to not overload you with irrelevant properties, getters and setters) I suddenly started experimenting and found the culprit. So thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Rubber-ducking at its finest.

Comment: @Jakumi You also got me into the right direction. The question was not only why Topic didn't work, but why the others worked. It was all in the association! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer: In my efforts to not add complexity to my entities (yet) I didn't feel the need to add the inverse side of the association.

So my Location looked like this:

```
class Location
{ 
     /** @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected int $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    protected string $Name;

    // [...] other fields and getters and setters omitted
}
```

and my Topic looked like this:

```
class Topic
{ 
     /** @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected int $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") */
    protected string $Name;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location", inversedBy="Topics")     * */
    protected Location $Location;

    // [...] other fields and getters and setters omitted
}
```

What I *didn't* include in Location was the

```
    /** @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Topic", mappedBy="Location") */
    protected Collection $Topics;
```

which I thought was optional, in case you wanted to use the wonderful automagic of Doctrine getting all objects for you.

But no, it wasn't optional. Without specifying the OneToMany relationship nothing was persisted.

I guess I need to reread [this](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) and try to actually understand it this time.

Does anybody know why no error was thrown and why my entities where *silently* ignored?

Comment: *if* you have `inversedBy` set (which isn't required by default, but if you do -> bidirectional) you need the matching inverse side - obviously - with the proper `mappedBy`. unidirectional is also possible, in that case there is no `inversedBy` on the owning side (the many-to-one side). Also, doctrine will only *ever* look on the owning side to determine if the relation changed (which also is the side where the db column is ...) Why persistence didn't work? Probably because the mapping had an error...